# Returning raw html from Vue to Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to preview input of form to another div as html markdown.

```
<div class="form-group" id="form">
  {!! Form::open(['route' => 'post.create']) !!}
    {{ Form::text('title', 'title', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('category_id', $category->id) }}
    {{ Form::textarea('body', 'body', ['class' => 'form-control', 'v-model' => 'input']) }}
    <div><?php echo '{{{ output }}}'; ?></div>
    {{ Form::submit('send', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-default btn-block']) }}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

On `app.js`:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    data: {
      input: '',
      output: ''
    },
    watch: {
      input: function(val) {
        this.output = marked(val);
      }
    }
});
```

`@{{{ output }}}}` returns the same result which is blank page with error on console:

```
- invalid expression: Unexpected token ) in

_s({ output)+"}"

Raw expression: {{{ output }}}
```

Comment: Why are you doing php echo at blade????

Comment: it's basicly same as doing `@{{{ output }}}` as everyone else suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your output is raw html use:

```
<div v-html="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's the one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-text="output"></div>
```

or

```
<div>@{{ output }}</div>
```

or using old way in watch ...

```
input: function(val) {
    this.output = marked(val);
    $('div.output').text(this.output);
}
```

Comment: mersi azizam, but this returns with html tags as string