# RAW HTML tags get stripped off when passed from Laravel to Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am adding Vue support to an existing Laravel system. Some of the data fields contain HTML tags.

Rendering it in Laravel was easy with the {!! option.

While passing it to Vue, I am seeing that some of the tags are getting omitted out.

For e.g.

Data passed from Laravel - I have verified this with the dd command in the blade.

```
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

gets passed to Vue as below

This is the data received in Vue. I have verified it with console.log and Vue developer tools.

```
    List1</li>List 2</li>List 3</li>
```

Any pointers on what I could be doing wrong would be great.

Comment: _"gets passed to vue as"_... did you miss something here in your question? If you want to get Vue to insert HTML, you need to use the [`v-html` directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning raw html from Vue to Laravel Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169139/returning-raw-html-from-vue-to-laravel-blade)

Comment: I understand the v-html directive will help display the html. My issue is that the data received by Vue is incorrect. Some of the tags have got stripped off in transit.

Comment: Maybe some encoding issue? Check the raw content passed in the server logs or network tab.

Comment: can you add code which causes the issue in .blade

Comment: @php
    <product-detail product-data="{{ $product}}"></product-detail>

Comment: $product here is a resultset of a Model search. I have also tried explicitly json_encoding it and sending the string . No change.

Comment: have you tried :product-data = "{{ json_encode($product) }}"

Comment: is ```List1</li>List 2</li>List 3</li>``` the source code, or its what you see in browser

Comment: other property of $product remaining the same, only the HTML property?

Comment: Can you post some examples of your vue code please?

Comment: I've just recreated this in its simplest form and it works... [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-flower-y7syk). There is clearly something happening to your lists before they are passed to the Vue component props.

Comment: or maybe an escape string error, replace double quote with single quote:  :product-data = '{{ json_encode($product) }}'

Comment: Can you please show the code you pass the data from controller to view and also the view with the usage of v-html. Right now you are just explaining what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I had some reactions to my vaccine second shot and was resting for the past 2-3 days.

Comment: @ChinhNguyen I have tried the different options you have mentioned.

Comment: @JustCarty . Thanks for the sandbox but there seems to be some issue at the Laravel end.

Comment: @mrhn - As I have mentioned, I have tested the code from the controller by doing a dd at the blade level. The data shows up as intended

Comment: @thursday_dan - I am using v-html in the vue code but it doesn't really matter because I can see the problem before its get rendered via the vue developer tools and console.log

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It's all about XSS vulnerabilities. A workaround could be using slot on vue component and echo rendered view but using props is also possible.

**ExampleComponent.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Returning rendered view :

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test.index', ['view' => view('test.list', ['num' => 5])->render()]);
});
```

**test\index.blade.php**

```php
<example-component>
    {!!$view!!}
</example-component>
```

and **test\list.blade.php**

```php
<div >
    <ul>
        @for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) 
            <li>List {{$i+1}}</li>
        @endfor
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can also use props but you need v-html directive:

**ExampleComponent.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-html="view"></span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
props:['view']};
</script>
```

**test\index.blade.php**

```php
<example-component view="{{$view}}">
   
</example-component>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try the first approach. I have tried the second approach and it does not work.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I should get back to this issue by this weekend. I will ping you once I have worked on it again.